# Derivative of matrix as a function of a vector w.r.t a vector

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives

I want to compute the derivative of the matrix $ diag(x)M $ with respect to $ x $, where $ x \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times 1} $ and $ M \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times m} $. This is how I have approached it, but I have not been successful.

First,
$$ Y = diag(x) $$

Then,
$$ Z = Y M  $$

The differential of $ Z $ is
$$
   dZ = dY M
$$

If I am not mistaken $ dY = (I_{n \times n} \otimes 1_{n \times 1}) dx $. So
$$
   dZ = (I_{n \times n} \otimes 1_{n \times 1}) (dx) M
$$

But the dimensions do not make much sense in this last expression. Would you please help me to find the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mixed vec-diag expression can rearranged using [the formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2993406/) 
$${\rm vec}\Big(A\,{\rm Diag}(b)\,C\Big) = \Big((C^T\otimes 1_a)\odot(1_c\otimes A)\Big)\,b$$
In this case the variables of interest are $(A=I_n,\,\,C=M,\,\,b=dx),\,$ therefore
$$\eqalign{
{\rm vec}(dZ) &= {\rm vec}\Big(I_n\,\,{\rm Diag}(dx)\,\,M\Big) \cr
dz &= \Big((M^T\otimes 1_n)\odot(1_m\otimes I_n)\Big)\,dx \cr
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} &= (M^T\otimes 1_n)\odot(1_m\otimes I_n) \cr
}$$

Comment: Perfect! Thank you greg!