# Changing Side of Vector in Matrix Equation

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, linear-transformations, singularity, pseudoinverse

Let $j$ and $b$ be $k*1$ vectors and $y$ be an $n*1$ vector. I am bit stuck on how to solve for $b$ in the following equation:
$$j^Tb=y^Ty$$
If $j$ were a matrix, we could, multiply both sides of the equation with $j$ and then with $(jj^T)^{-1}$. However, given that $j$  is a vector, $jj^T$ or $uj^T$ for any $k*1$ vector $u$ is a singular matrix and therefore cannot be inverted.

I suspect I cannot see something obvious here...Any ideas (other than applying singular value decomposition)?

Comment: There will be a whole plane of solutions in general. You can try taking a numerical example at the start, say $j = \begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix}, b=\begin{bmatrix}b_1\\ b_2\\ b_3\end{bmatrix}$ and $y = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$. Then $y^Ty$ (which is always just a number) is equal to $3$ and $j^T b = b_1+2b_2+3b_3$. So the equation you want to solve is $$b_1+2b_2+3b_3 = 3.$$ As you should know, this is the equation of a plane, for which you can find many solutions.

Comment: I want to move j to the other side of the equation. For example, if $jj^T$ could be inverted, we could have $b=(jj^T)^{-1}jy^Ty$ which would be a k*1 vector

Comment: You can’t really “move it to the other side.” However, an obvious solution to the equation when $j\ne0$ is $b=(j^Tj)^{-1}(y^Ty)j$. Of course, as @MinusOne-Twelfth points out, if $j^Tc=0$, then $b+c$ is also a solution.

Comment: Apologies, but I do not understand how you can get to $b=(j^Tj)^{-1}(y^Ty)j$ . If $jj^T$ were not singular then, we could get  $b=(jj^T)^{-1}jy^Ty$, but we cannot, because we cannot invert $jj^T$, which is my problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the linear system $Mv=p$, all possible solutions (if they exist) are given by
$$\eqalign{v &= M^+p + (I-M^+M)\,a}$$
where $M^+$ is the pseudoinverse of $M$, $I$ is the identity matrix, and $a$ is an arbitrary vector.

In the current problem 
$$\eqalign{
v &= b,\quad p = y^Ty,\quad M = j^T,\quad M^+ = \frac{j}{j^Tj} \\
}$$
yielding
$$\eqalign{
b
 &= \Bigg(\frac{y^Ty}{j^Tj}\bigg)\,j + \Bigg(I-\frac{jj^T}{j^Tj}\Bigg)\,a \\
 &= \frac{1}{j^Tj}\bigg(\big(y^Ty-j^Ta\big)j + \big(j^Tj\big)a\bigg) \\
}$$
The choice of the $a$-vector completely determines the solution vector.

Comment: Thank you. I now understand what the comments above indicated, but thanks for the comprehensive explanation. In case we have $jj^Tb=jy^Ty$ and therefore, vector = vector, rather than scalar = scalar, but we still cannot obviously invert $jj^T$; then, is singular value decomposition our only option?