# Inverting Product of Vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, inverse, singularity

Let $j$ be an $n*1$ vector. Then, $jj^T$ is an $n*n$ singular matrix. Is the pseudo-inverse or any other application of Singular Value Decomposition going to lead to a meaningful result in this case? For example, in equation $$jj^Tb=aj$$ where $j$ and $b$ are $n*1$ vectors and $a$ is a scalar, is there a way of getting a meaningful solution for vector $b$?

Comment: For your example, you're looking for the matrices satisfying $j(j^Tb - a) = 0$.  In other words, $b$ solves the equation iff $j^Tb = a$.

Comment: The pseudonorm would produce the solution with minimal magnitude, I don't know if you consider this solution particularly "meaningful" in your context.

Comment: Can you please define the pseudonorm in this case? Apologies, but I am not 100% sure what exactly this means. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say pseudoinverse, as in the Moore-Penrose inverse.

Comment: I think that the Moore-Penrose inverse turns out to be
$$
(jj^T)^+ = \frac{jj^T}{(j^Tj)^2}
$$

Comment: I agree that this is the pseudo-inverse in this case and therefore, the best solution should be $b=a\frac{jj^T}{(j^Tj)^2}j$. I would be interested to know if anyone disagrees though. Thank you.

Comment: Well, I will say that @Omnomnomnom's original comment assumes that $j \ne 0$, but that is a really minor nitpick. Also, $j^Tb = a$ is the equation of an $n-1$ dimensional affine subspace. So even though your solution has minimal norm, keep in mind that it is far from the only solution. And, depending on what future use is to be made of $b$, it is possible that another solution would be better. Other than these small caveats, it is pretty easy to verify that everything is correct.

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3347117/265466) about this equation, which has an accepted answer?

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough, but I wanted to primarily focus on the "inversion" of $jj^T$ rather than the solution of the particular equation. In that sense, despite the perfect answer in my previous question, I found the comments from Omnomnomnom and Paul Sinclair particularly helpful. To build on what @Paul Sinclair wrote: Assume that any solution for $b$ in this case, sets the gradient of a function to 0 and is therefore a local max/min. Is there anything else we can do other than iteratively search the space of all solutions for $b$ (local max/min) to locate the global max/min?  Thanks