# Differentiation of Scalar with respect to Vector, Second Order, involving Hadamard Products

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, trace, chain-rule

I need to calculate the Gradient of the scalar $y^Ty$, with respect to vector $x$:
$$y= (((R((G^T((Exl^T)\circ P))\circ W))\circ S)\circ H)l$$
$$\frac{\partial y^Ty}{\partial x}=\frac{2}{u^Tu}jj^Tx?$$
where $y$, $x$ and $l$ are vectors and the rest of the terms are matrices:

*Dimensions: R:(g * g), G:(e* g), E(e*k), x(1*k), l(p*1), P(e*p), W,S,H(g *p)

Following [this elegant solution involving traces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3338071/differentiating-scalar-product-of-matrix-and-hadamard-multiplications-applying/3338301?noredirect=1#comment6872593_3338301), it can be shown that:

$$u^Ty=j:x \implies u^Ty=j^Tx$$ where: $$j=E^T((G((R^T((ul^T)\circ H\circ S))\circ W))\circ P)l$$

I am using a little trick to calculate the Gradient of $y^Ty$ with respect to $x$:

$$y^Tyu^Tu=yy^T:u^Tu = u^Tyy^T:u^T=u^Ty:u^Ty \implies$$
$$y^Tyu^Tu=(J^Tx)^Tj^Tx=x^Tjj^Tx \implies$$
$$y^Ty=\frac{1}{u^Tu}x^Tjj^Tx\implies$$
$$\frac{\partial y^Ty}{\partial x}=\frac{2}{u^Tu}jj^Tx$$

I am getting to the same solution, applying product rule:

$$\partial (y^Ty)=\partial (y^T)y+(y^T(\partial (y))^T)^T$$
$$\frac{\partial y^Tu}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u^Ty}{\partial x}=j$$
$$\partial (y^Tu)=\partial (y^T)u+(y^T(\partial (u))^T)^T \implies \frac{\partial(y^T)}{\partial x}=ju^T(uu^T)^+$$
$$\partial (u^Ty)=\partial (u^T)y+(u^T(\partial (y))^T)^T \implies \frac{\partial(y)}{\partial x}=ju^T(uu^T)^+$$
I believe we can write $y$ as: $$y=(uu^T)^+uj^Tx$$
From the above equations, I get again:
$$\frac{\partial y^Ty}{\partial x}=\frac{2}{u^Tu}jj^Tx$$

I think that I am doing sth wrong, because combining this derivation with a couple of others, I end up getting many solutions, despite having more equations than unknowns. My hunch is that where I have $jj^T$, I should be having a full rank $(k)$ matrix instead. Any ideas are welcome! Thanks.

(I had a typo in the dimensions of $E$; Apologies if this caused trouble to anyone before fixed)

Comment: The first derivation is incorrect because
$$\eqalign{
y^Ty\;u^Tu &= uy^T:uy^T \ne u^Ty:u^Ty
}$$
To recover $y$, you must use a set of orthonormal vectors $(u_k)$ in place of the single vector $(u)$, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
j_k &= E^T(\ldots(u_kl^T)\ldots)l \\
y &= \sum_k u_k(u_k^Ty) = \sum_k u_k(j_k^Tx) \\
}$$

Comment: To finish my previous comment, set $\,M = \sum_k u_kj_k^T\;$ then
$$\eqalign{
y &= Mx \\
\phi &= y^Ty = Mx:Mx \\
d\phi &= 2Mx:M\,dx = 2M^TMx:dx \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x} &= 2M^TMx \\
}$$
This assumes that you've calculated those $j_k$-vectors correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comprehensive solutions. The only thing I am not sure about is how many orthonormal vectors we need? Is it $k$ (matching $x$) or $g$ (matching $y$)? The latter would be somewhat computationally expensive...

Comment: Unfortunately it is the latter, $$y=\sum_{i=1}^g u_i j_i^T x$$ Note that the identity matrix is $$I_g = \sum_{i=1}^g u_i u_i^T$$

Comment: Is it correct to state that by the use of orthonormal vectors, you are cancelling out $u$ and as a result, $M$ is independent from $u$ @greg?

Comment: Yes, any complete set of orthonormal vectors will work. But you must use the same set of vectors for the calculation of the $(j_k)$ vectors.

Comment: Thank you. I had verified the solution straight away. However, the only issue is its quadratic complexity, as computational time is a quadratic function of $g$. But, the fact that $M$ is not a function of $u$ helps a lot, because I do not have to recalculate $M$ each time $u$ changes (which happens a lot). This is not a problem in your main solution below, but that leads me to some matrices with $billion^2$ elements, which I am trying to simplify. For example, I believe I can use $vec(P)$ instead of its diagonalised matrix and apply vector to matrice element wise multiplication  @greg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectorization followed by diagonalization will prove to be a useful operation, so let's create a notation for it.
$$\eqalign{
{\cal P} &= {\rm Diag}\Big({\rm vec}(P)\Big) \\
{\cal W} &= {\rm Diag}\Big({\rm vec}(W)\Big) \\
}$$
Define the matrices
$$\eqalign{
A &= Exl^T\odot P \\
B &= W\odot G^TA \\
C &= S\odot H \\
}$$
Then consider their factorizations/vectorizations.
$$\eqalign{
C &= \sum_k \sigma_ku_kv_k^T, \quad U_k = {\rm Diag}(\sigma_ku_k),\;
V_k = {\rm Diag}(v_k) \\
C\odot Z &= \sum_kU_kZV_k \\
a &= {\rm vec}(A) \\
  &= {\rm vec}(P)\odot{\rm vec}(Exl^T) \\
  &= {\rm vec}(P)\odot(l\otimes E)x \\
  &= {\cal P} (l\otimes E)x \\
b &= {\rm vec}(B) \\
  &= {\rm vec}(W)\odot{\rm vec}(G^TA) \\
  &= {\cal W}(I\otimes G^T)a \\
  &= {\cal W}(I\otimes G^T){\cal P} (l\otimes E)x \\
  &= Qx \\
}$$
Use all of this to write $y$ in a nicer form.
$$\eqalign{
y
 &= (S\odot H\odot R(W\odot(G^T(Exl^T\odot P))))l \\
 &= (S\odot H\odot R(W\odot(G^TA)))l \\
 &= (C\odot RB)l \\
 &= \sum_k {\rm vec}\Big(U_k RB V_k l\Big)
  = \sum_k (l^TV_k\otimes U_kR)\,b \\
 &= Jb \\&= JQx \\
}$$
With this nice expression for $y$, finding the gradient of the objective function is simple.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= y^Ty \\ &= y:y \\
d\phi &= 2y:dy \\
 &= 2y:JQ\,dx \\
 &= 2\,Q^TJ^Ty:dx \\
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}
 &= 2\,Q^TJ^Ty \\
 &= 2\,(l^T\otimes E^T)\;{\cal P}\;(I\otimes G)\;{\cal W}\;
 \sum_k\Big(V_kl\otimes R^TU_k\Big)\;y \\
}$$
To relate this to my previous comments, note that $\;M=JQ$.

#### Update

The variables $(U_k,V_k)$ can be removed from the final expression since
$$\eqalign{
\sum_k\Big(V_kl\otimes R^TU_k\Big)\;y 
 &= {\rm vec}\bigg(\sum_k R^TU_kyl^TV_k\bigg) \\ 
 &= {\rm vec}\Big(R^T\big(yl^T\odot C\big)\Big) 
  = {\rm vec}\Big(R^TYCL\Big) \\
&{where}\quad Y = {\rm Diag}(y),\; L = {\rm Diag}(l) \\
}$$
This means that you don't need to perform an SVD decompostion to utilize the result.