# Differentiating an expression involving Hadamard Product

Tags: matrix-calculus, hadamard-product

I'm trying to calculate $\frac{dY}{dW}$ where:
$$Y = (W^TX)oC$$

- 'o' denotes the hadamard product. W, X and C are matrices with dimension (d, c), (d, n) and (c, n) respectively.

From [matrix cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf):, I understand $$\frac{dW^TX}{dW}=X$$

But, not able to figure out how to account for the hadamard product in the expression. I saw some other [responses](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3338071/differentiating-scalar-product-of-matrix-and-hadamard-multiplications-applying) on similar topic but it was hard to follow. Some intuition from a beginners' perspective will be very helpful.